# Why C# Arrays type IsSerializable property is True?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, serialization

I was just curious why C# arrays return `true` for their `IsSerializable` property.  Arrays do not have any `Serializable` attribute, and they also don't implement the `ISerializable` interface, so why is the `IsSerializable` property set to `true`?

When I try the below code, it outputs "True" in the console:

```cs
Console.WriteLine (new string[0].GetType().IsSerializable);
```

The output is:

```cs
True
```

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/OPUP80446)

My .NET runtime version is 3.5.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: @EdPlunkett I looked through the documentation you linked to, but I can't find anything that seems applicable to the question.

Comment: @dahui There is no useful information. [This link is correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx)

Comment: @BJMyers Good point.

Comment: @HasanBayat I was linking to that as it might explain to the OP what the IsSerializable property is

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> `Arrays` does not have any `Serializable` attribute and also they aren't implement `ISerializable` interface

`Array` class, an implicit base class of C# arrays, has `[SerializableAttribute]`:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, 
    IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

[(reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx)

It also appears that the compiler adds `[SerializableAttribute]` to the array type itself

```
foreach (var a in typeof(string[]).GetCustomAttributes(false)) {
    Console.WriteLine(a); // Prints "System.SerializableAttribute"
}
```

Passing `false` to [`GetCustomAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254(v=vs.110).aspx) ensures that only attributes for this class, and not for its base classes, are returned.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/61nSvh)

Comment: Why, the base class of that, `System.Object`, also carries the `[Serializable]` attribute? What version of the runtime do you use to have `typeof(string[]).GetCustomAttributes(false)` return that attribute? One final question: Is it implicit in your answer that there is a relation between what `IsSerializable` returns for a `System.Type` object, and whether the class it represents carries the `[Serializable]` attribute or not?

Comment: I tried to investigate some of my own remarks. It appears that `IsSerializable` reflects whether there is a `[Serializable]` attribute in most case, but some enum types and delegate types are exceptions. To me it seems array types, like `string[]`, are exceptions as well? The attribute is not inherited (if it were, all classes would inherit it since it decorates `System.Object`, as I said).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks for a great comment! I investigated this as well, and it looks like the implementation is deep in the guts of the CLR. The code in the demo runs on ideone, so I am not sure what version of runtime they are using. When I ran this on the latest runtime from Microsoft, I got no attributes back, even when passing `true` to `GetCustomAttributes`. At this point I think that marking classes serializable is a CLR magic, hidden in the native implementation of ` RuntimeTypeHandle.GetAttributes` method. I cannot locate the source for it, though.

Comment: Yes. Because the `class SerializableAttribute` has an `[AttributeUsage]` which sets `Inherited = false` (the default is true), I believe it is irrelevant whether you say pass `true` or `false` to `GetCustomeAttributes` when it comes to this case.